# Why does webpack need a loader for an import which I don't use?

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

Let's say I have this in my `index.js`

```
import { foo } from "./extra.js";
```

And then in my `extra.js` there's this

```
export function foo () { return 0; }
export function bar () { import("./baz.svg"); }
```

When I try to build, I get en error concerning `baz.svg`: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type".
Clearly I never use `bar` in my code, so why is webpack trying to bundle it? And how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is **tree shaking**. To enable tree shaking, you have to configure few optimization settings as shown [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

However, even with these settings, this problem would not be solved. That is because - the dead-code elimination or tree shaking happens after module resolution has happened. You can consider it as a thing that runs to optimize bundle after it is generate. Webpack will try to find a loader for importing `svg` file.

There are few things you can try but none are really foolproof to your need without any installation:

- [ignore-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader) (Most useful to match your requirements)
- [IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/)
- [Using magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments)

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. So no matter if I use some piece of code or not, webpack needs to be able to evaluate everything before tree shaking and optimization? Thanks.

Comment: @eudoxyz You are right. Webpack needs to create complete dependency graph before running optimizations. You can try Rollup.js if it does differently as it is more aggressive in doing this. But I am not entirely sure.

Comment: And if I tried magic comments, how would I proceed?

Comment: @eudoxyz Something like: `import(/* webpackExclude: /\.svg$/) */ "./baz.svg");`

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your webpack.config.json under the "rules" node:

```
{
test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 8192
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks. I already know how to add an appropriate loader, but I was wondering why do I need it in the first place if I never use or include certain parts of code which require it. I kind of thought webpack should be "smart" about this stuff.